# Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project add folder and file force refresh of project in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating an app that will add some files and folders to an existing project which is loaded in Visual studio.  That works but it will always pop up a message telling the user (me) to refresh the project to show the new files.

[image]

When using Entity Framework and adding a migration it will add a file to a project that is currently loaded and it doesn't ask the user.  I would like to be able to do the same thing.

Is this possible?  If someone doesn't know the answer do they know how I might delve into EF and add migration to see how they do it?

Here is the code that I am using to edit the project file:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

 internal class ProjectFileHandler
    {
        private void AddMigrationFolder(Project project, string     projectFileLocation, string name)
        {
            var loc = Path.Combine(projectFileLocation.Substring(0, projectFileLocation.LastIndexOf("\\")), name);
            project.AddItem("Folder", loc);            
        }

        internal void AddMigrationFile(string projectfileLocation, string migrationFolderName, string fileLocation)
        {
            var project = new Project(projectfileLocation);
            AddMigrationFolder(project, projectfileLocation, migrationFolderName);

            project.AddItem("Compile", fileLocation);

            project.Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: from memory I used DTE to do this.  I put it in this project if it would be helpful https://github.com/twistedtwig/NHibernateRepository

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old, but I'll leave a comment. Maybe it helps someone else.

The problem is the "project.Save();"

The solution recognizes this as an "external" change.
Try your code without this line.

Comment: Even I am also facing this issue. If you don't use project.Save(), then it will prompt you to overwrite the project file. Also, I want this change to be included before build is called. Has anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Even older, but I had to solve this problem today, so for what it's worth, here's what I did.

Firstly, as far as I can tell, you can't update a project using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation without Visual Studio prompting the user to reload it. You have to call `project.Save()` to write your updates to the project XML, and Visual Studio 'sees' the file change and displays the prompt.

What you *can* do - and this looks to be what Entity Framework does, albeit [with Powershell](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/99c172bc465492fa37f9efa07900653975ec79b4/src/EntityFramework.NuGet/tools/EntityFramework6.psm1#L287) - is use EnvDTE instead of Microsoft.Build.Evaluation. EnvDTE is available [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EnvDTE) and the latest version supports .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Standard 2, so it should be pretty widely compatible.

With EnvDTE you get a reference to a `Project` object and call `AddFromFile(absoluteFilePath)` - there are also other `Add()` methods if needed.

If you have the full file path to your project, you can get a project file using:

```cs
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using EnvDTE;

var dte = (DTE)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");

var project = dte
    .Solution
    .EnumerateProjects()
    .First(p => p.FullName == fullPathToProject);
```

...where `EnumerateProjects()` is the following extension method:

```cs
using EnvDTE;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

internal static class EnvDteExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Project> EnumerateProjects(
        this Solution solution)
    {
        return Enumerate(solution.Projects);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Project> Enumerate(IEnumerable items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var candidateProject = item;

            if (candidateProject is ProjectItem projectItem &&
                projectItem.SubProject != null)
            {
                candidateProject = projectItem.SubProject;
            }

            if (!(candidateProject is Project project))
            {
                continue;
            }

            yield return project;

            try
            {
                if (project.ProjectItems == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }

            foreach (var subProject in Enumerate(project.ProjectItems))
            {
                yield return subProject;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A `Project` in EnvDTE might actually be a project, or it might be a solution folder containing projects - the `candidateProject is ProjectItem projectItem && projectItem.SubProject != null` check handles the latter scenario.

EnvDTE's `Project.AddFromFile()` pops the file into Solution Explorer with no project reload prompt.

Finally, `AddFromFile()` seems to be idempotent, so you can spam the same file into the project without worrying if it already exists.