# Powershell and PMC $dte.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem error

Tags: c#, powershell, envdte

I am trying to write a powershell script to reload a project (files and folders have been added to it via a C# app (tried to do this via C# but failed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380646/microsoft-build-evaluation-project-add-folder-and-file-force-refresh-of-project)). My end goal is to be able to call the C# app then reload the project (unload and reload) to refresh the project and avoid the user having to manually say reload the project.

```
$project = Get-Project

write-host("starting NHMigrate on project: " + $project.Name)
$project.FullName
$project.UniqueName

$shortpath = $dte.Solution.Properties.Item("Name").Value + "\" +     $project.Name
$dte.Windows.Item("{3AE79031-E1BC-11D0-8F78-00A0C9110057}").Activate() 
$dte.ActiveWindow.Object
$dte.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem($project.UniqueName)
```

The problem I am having is everything I google says use GetItem to select that project to be able to call execute_command, but I get the exception

```
Exception calling "GetItem" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."
At E:\Work\nhibernateRepo\NHibernateRepository\NHMigrate\test.ps1:12 char:1
+ $dte.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem($project.UniqueName)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

I can't find anything on why this doesn't work.  Everyone seems to be calling get Item with a single param.  Ican't find the docs that covers this method either.

**EDIT**

This is a note about what I was trying to achieve.  Using powershell to refresh the project works but it doesn't stop, or remove the "File Modification Detected" dialog which was ultimately what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the method didn't work for me was that I was not using the correct path for the project.  it needs to be the same structure as the solution file, i.e.

```
sol[
  testfolder[
     ExampleRepo
]
```

and call it with:

```
$dte.ActiveWindow.Object.GetItem("sol\testfolder\ExampleRepo").Select(1)
```